# Button to execute PHP function within woocommerce customer order page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to make a button which will execute my FPDF script within the customers orders page of woocommerce so that customers can generate a pdf based on specific order the button is next to.

I've added the below my functions.php file to create a new column for the button and I have added the function which I want the button to execute as well.

I'm stuck as to how I can go about adding a new button to carry out the function to the myaccount/orders.php file. I've spent the better part of the last two days trying to find a solution - so any help would be super appreciated!

```
// END ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION

add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_orders_columns', 'add_custom_account_orders_column', 10, 1 );
function add_custom_account_orders_column( $columns ) {
$ordered_columns = array();

// Inserting a new column in a specific location
$ordered_columns['order-number'] = $columns['order-number'];
$ordered_columns['order-date'] = $columns['order-date'];
$ordered_columns['order-status'] = $columns['order-status'];
$ordered_columns['order-total'] = $columns['order-total'];
$ordered_columns['order-actions'] = $columns['order-actions'];
$ordered_columns['order-downloads'] =  __( 'Downloads', 'woocommerce' ); // <== New column

return $ordered_columns;
}
```

function to call FPDF

```
function exFDPI () {
   require_once("/file/directory/FPDF.php");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first your missing the content in your new column so here is how to do it:

**Step 1 : add our column**

```
add_filter('woocommerce_account_orders_columns', 'add_custom_account_orders_column', 10, 1);
function add_custom_account_orders_column($columns)
{
$ordered_columns = array();

// Inserting a new column in a specific location
$ordered_columns['order-number'] = $columns['order-number'];
$ordered_columns['order-date'] = $columns['order-date'];
$ordered_columns['order-status'] = $columns['order-status'];
$ordered_columns['order-total'] = $columns['order-total'];
$ordered_columns['order-actions'] = $columns['order-actions'];
$ordered_columns['order-downloads'] = __('Downloads', 'woocommerce'); // <== New column

return $ordered_columns;
}
```

**Step 2: add our Form content to our new column**

```
//Insert the content into the new column 
function pdf_column_content($order)
{
    ?>



    <form action="<?php echo esc_url(admin_url('admin-post.php')); ?>" method="post">
    <?php wp_nonce_field('pdf_temp');?> //Security Check
        <input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="<?php echo $order->get_order_number() ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="pdf_temp">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>


<?php 
}
add_action('woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_order-downloads', 'pdf_column_content');
```

**Step 3 Final Step: add our action in WordPress way**

```
//when the user click submit then we will call our template 
function exFDPI()
{

    $retrieved_nonce = $_REQUEST['_wpnonce']; 
    if (!wp_verify_nonce($retrieved_nonce, 'pdf_temp')) { //if passed the security check proceed 
        wp_die('Failed security check');
    } else {

        $order_id = $_POST['order_id'];
        echo $order_id;
        require_once "/file/directory/FPDF.php";
    }

}

add_action('admin_post_nopriv_pdf_temp', 'exFDPI');
add_action('admin_post_pdf_temp', 'exFDPI');
```

of course the full code should go into your theme `functions.php`

code above tested.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass parameter with the button and then handle the request on `init` hook.

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_orders_columns', 'add_custom_account_orders_column', 10, 1 );
    function add_custom_account_orders_column( $columns ) {
    $ordered_columns = array();

    // Inserting a new column in a specific location
    $ordered_columns['order-number'] = $columns['order-number'];
    $ordered_columns['order-date'] = $columns['order-date'];
    $ordered_columns['order-status'] = $columns['order-status'];
    $ordered_columns['order-total'] = $columns['order-total'];
    $ordered_columns['order-actions'] = $columns['order-actions'];
    $ordered_columns['order-downloads'] = __('Downloads', 'woocommerce'); // <== New column

    return $ordered_columns;
    }





function exFDPI () {
if(isset($_POST['order_id_for_pdf'])) {
require_once("/file/directory/FPDF.php");
//

return;
}
else {
return;
}     
}
add_action( 'init', 'exFDPI' );
```

Dont forget to add `return;`

**UPDATE**

Add content to button as @kashalo tells in his answer.

```
    //Insert the content into the new column 
    function pdf_column_content($order)
    {
        ?>


    <div id="content">
    <form action="<?php esc_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ?>" method="post">
         <input type="hidden" name="order_id_for_pdf" value="<?php echo $order->get_order_number() ?>">
         <input type="submit" value="Downloads">
         </form>
    </div>

<?php 
}
add_action('woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_order-downloads', 'pdf_column_content');
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply! I've tried putting that in my functions.php and it filled one of the table headers with the <form action="' .... </form> part for some reason? sorry im quite new to this

Comment: Check Updated Answer.